# Regex for domain extraction

Tags: java, regex

I use the following regex which extracts domain names and urls with/without schema and `www`:

```
(https?://)?\w+(\.\w+)+(/\w+)*(/\w+\.\w+)?(\?[\w%&=.]*)*(?=[^\w.?&%=])
```

that works fine in most of the cases, for example for `www.medicare.gov`

But it doesn't work in case of input text `www.medicare.gov.`

How to fix it in order to support such or similar cases also?

Comment: @Zenoo, yes but `www.medicare.co.uk` is valid

Comment: @Andremoniy It is not the duplicate  - I'm not going to validate the full input string for domain validity but I'd like to extract the domain from this string